# Dispatching S4 methods based on long combination of arguments

Tags: r, generics, methods, r-s4

## Motivation

I am trying to create a generic R function that dispatches methods depending not on the signature of the main argument (`n`), but on the presence of secondary arguments.

I am not sure if this is possible in S3, but I know how to do it in S4 (albeit in a sloppy manner, as you might notice). No idea about R5 or S6.

## MRE

```r
setGeneric(
    name = "genfunk",
    def  = function(n, a, b, c, d) standardGeneric("genfunk"),
    signature = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
)
setMethod(
    f = "genfunk",
    signature = list(
        a = "numeric",
        b = "numeric",
        c = "missing",
        d = "missing"
    ),
    definition = function(n, a, b) n + a + b
)
setMethod(
    f = "genfunk",
    signature = list(
        a = "missing",
        b = "missing",
        c = "numeric",
        d = "numeric"
    ),
    definition = function(n, c, d) n * c * d
)
```

This allows me to call the functions and get things like:

```r
r$> genfunk(10, a=1, b=2)                                                                        
[1] 13

r$> genfunk(10, c=3, d=2)                                                                        
[1] 60
```

## Problem

The problem is that mixed calls will yield "nonsense" to the user:

```r
r$> genfunk(10, a=1, c=2)                                                                        
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘genfunk’ for signature ‘"numeric", "missing", "numeric", "missing"’
```

## Questions

1. Is it possible to create an "exception" signature to handle all these improper argument mismatches?
2. Is it possible to rename the valid signatures so that they are properly labeled in the documentation? In my real case, the documentation of `genfunk` contains stuff like:

```r
## S4 method for signature 
## 'numeric,numeric,missing,missing'
genfunk(n, a, b)

## S4 method for signature 
## 'missing,missing,numeric,numeric'
genfunk(n, c, d)
```

which makes no sense to a user unless they look at the code for the generic. Things in my actual code are even worse, since the signature list currently contains almost two dozen arguments from a dozen different methods (and counting).

I think the trick ought to be somewhere in the documentation, but I feel like I've ran out of things to try. Currently, the generic is documented as:

```r
#' @title Yes, title!
#' @param n Enn
#' @export
```

and each method is documented as:

```r
#' @title AB funk
#' @param a Ehi!
#' @param b Bee
#' @rdname genfunk
```

Comment: so, in short, -  you want to have methods for each combination of arguments?

Comment: @tjebo, almost. I'd like to have methods for some (mutually-exclusive) combinations of arguments and, is possible, an umbrella one for the rest (just to provide the user with some useful feedback on how to use the generic).

Comment: Have you looked at the help page for `dotsMethods`? Can your function work with `...` as an argument in place of named arguments?

Comment: @JDL, thank you for pointing that out, I didn't know there was a doc page for this. I'll give it a go and get back here if I make progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is not S4, but from the way you asked the question I believe you might also be curious for a possible S3 solution. If I understand you correctly, you want to dispatch methods based on the presence of certain combinations of named arguments. I think there is no way around manually defining methods for each combination that you want to allow, and then create a "default method" for the rest. One way to dispatch based on the arguments in S3 would be:

```r
genfunk <- function(x, ...){
   newclass <- paste(names(list(...)), collapse = "_")
   class(x) <- c(newclass, class(x))
   genfunkInt(x, ...)
}
genfunkInt <- function(x, ...){
  UseMethod("genfunkInt", x)
}
genfunkInt.a_b <- function(...) {
  Reduce(`+`, list(...))
}
genfunkInt.c_d <- function(...) {
  Reduce(`*`, list(...))
}
genfunkInt.default <- function(x, ...) {
  stop("Weird combination of arguments", call. = FALSE)
}

genfunk(10, a=1, b=2)                                                                        
#> [1] 13
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "a_b"     "numeric"

genfunk(10, c=3, d=2)
#> [1] 60
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "c_d"     "numeric"

genfunk(10, a=1, c=2) 
#> Error: Weird combination of arguments
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! I don't really care which object system I end up using. Your idea of defining the class inside the generic surely sounds promising, I'll give that a shot.